# Como utilizar javascript para tornar uma div visível e ocultar outra?

Tags: javascript, css

Olá,

Tenho 3 div's: uma que funciona como botão e outras duas como caixa de cores.

Preciso que ao clicar na `div` que funciona como botão a `div` **COR 2** feche e a **COR 1** fique visível.

**Esta funciona como botão:**

```
<div onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')">ALTERNAR</div>
```

**Estas são caixas de cores:**

```
<div id="minhaDiv" style="display:none;">COR 1</div>
<div id="minhaDiv" style="display:block;">COR 2</div>
```

**Java Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmadeletar(el) {
        var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "none")
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: tu percebeu que o id das divs estão iguais? id="minhaDiv"

Comment: ideal nesse caso é ter uma div só e ai alternar a classe css cada uma com estilo diferente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O id das `divs` estão iguais e você não está chamando a função que está no script, veja como fica após as correções:

```html
<div onclick="Mudarestado()">ALTERNAR</div>

<div id="minhaDiv1" style="display:none;">COR 1</div>
<div id="minhaDiv2" style="display:block;">COR 2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Mudarestado(el) {
        var display1 = document.getElementById('minhaDiv1').style.display;
        var display2 = document.getElementById('minhaDiv2').style.display;
        if(display1 == "none") {
            document.getElementById('minhaDiv1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('minhaDiv2').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('minhaDiv2').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('minhaDiv1').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma `<div>` fazer papel de botão é estranho e não ajuda os leitores de tela e nem a semântica de um documento HTML.

Mas, de qualquer maneira, a solução performática seria usar CSS para mostrar/esconder as `<div>`s onde ao colocar e tirar uma classe de um elemento pai os filhos são mostrados ou escondidos.

Abaixo um exemplo usando os métodos `Element.classList.toggle()` e `Element.classList.contains()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList));

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('alternar')
const elementoPai = document.getElementById('elemento-pai')

btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    elementoPai.classList.toggle('ativa')
})
```

```css
#elemento-pai > .uma-div { display: block; }
#elemento-pai > .outra-div { display: none; }

#elemento-pai.ativa > .uma-div { display: none; }
#elemento-pai.ativa > .outra-div { display: block; }

.uma-div { background-color: tomato; }
.outra-div { background-color: gold; }
```

```html
<button id="alternar">Alternar</button>
<hr>
<div id="elemento-pai">
  <div class="uma-div">Div 1</div>
  <div class="outra-div">Div 2</div>
</div>
```